# How to read text from an inputstream, formatted as XML, with a BufferedReader.readLine() method?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, inputstream

I have an xml file which I included as a resource in my netbeans project.

Now, I try to read it line by line with an inputstream reader:

```
static InputStream nudeMap = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("overlay_map_2007.txt");

static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nudeMap,"UTF-8"));
```

=> this get met the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:80)
```

I checked the encoding of the file and it is indeed UTF-8, so I don't think it is an encoding problem. I have no experience here, but I suspect it might come from the fact that the file is actually xml formatted. First lines are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gexf xmlns:viz="http:///www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft">
```

My point is, I don't want to write a parser for the use I have of the file. Do you have any clue about how I could read it as a plain old text file, without errors? Thx!

[EDIT]: to make clear: I want to read this file with br.readLine(); not with a Java Parser!

Comment: Are you sure the file is at the correct location in the classpath after building? / Not using an XML parser on XML is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like that your textfile isn't being found.  In other words, I would guess that `getResourceAsStream` is returning `null`, and this null value is causing the NullPointerException you're getting.

Where is the `overlay_map_2007.txt` file within your project?

If this file isn't in the 'default' package, then you need to need to 'qualify' the name of the resource.  For example, if it lies within a folder `com.example.myproject`, the resource name would be `com/example/myproject/overlay_map_2007.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll even have to go that far.  A simple Google search yielded this fine example with its DOM Parser:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Have a thing against DOM, then there's SAX:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: Didn't see the "asAStream" part... how about this?

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to make clear that I am not interested in an xml parser. I simply want to use the classic bufferedReader.readLine() method: is it possible on an xml formatted file? Could it be the source of this null pointer exception I get? Thx!